# Print JavaScript dictionary into div

Tags: javascript, string, dictionary

I have a JavaScript map that looks like this

```
var code = {'as':'','db':'','id3':'','term':''};
```

And want to print for example `as` into a div. If I do this, I get 'Undefined' inside the div. As I understand, this means the value itself is undefined. How can I "predefine" the empty string?

**Update:**

As there seems to be a lot of confusion: If I put code[1] into a div using the code above, the div contains 'Undefined'.

**Update:**

The markup looks as follows

```
<div id="cont" class="diff">
    <div id="editor">
        <div id="funcRow">
            <ul>
                <li><a onclick="changeTab(0)">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="changeTab(1)">Knowledge</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="changeTab(2)">Layer 4</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="changeTab(3)">Hardware</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="text" contenteditable=true>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and changeTab(i) looks as follows:

```
function changeTab(i) {
    code[activeTab] = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = code[i];
    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className="active";
    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[activeTab].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className="";
    activeTab = i;
}
```

Comment: What would empty string be "predefine"d to ?

Comment: Can you add code that will display the value in the `<div>`

Comment: Empty strings don't just magically become `undefined`, you're doing something wrong ?

Comment: The current code that defines the innerHTML is document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = code[i]; where i is an integer from 0 to 3

Comment: @Jouh You cannot use index(_you can, but this is not what you want_) on object, use `code.as` or `code['as']` to get the value of key `as`.

Comment: @Tushar actually using ff's console trying code[1]; prints a value. Why is it that if JS can't iterate over a map this works?

Comment: What is the expected output, add the result markup

Comment: Looks like you should be using an array as you're assuming there will be order, and objects have no order.

Comment: I actually want to be able to do both, iterate as using an array and use keys. I just recently tried to get into JavaScript, but am pretty used to Python. I guess I projected too much.

Comment: @Jouh See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: _"If I do this, I get 'Undefined' inside the div."_ `activeTab` appear `undefined` ? Try defining `activeTab` , initially, outside of `changeTab` ; e.g., `var activeTab = "as"` ; though still passing indexes instead of property names  to `changeTab` ?

Comment: You can use `for (var prop in code) ` to iterate through the keys of a map. BUT, the order the props are returned is not guaranteed.

Comment: Alright, I understand. So there is no easy way too iterate over a map while keeping the order. Thank you

Comment: @Jouh There is, but it requires two objects, see my answer... (the 2nd part)

Answer (score 1):

The code below should be self-explanatory, just stringify before outputting

```js
var div = document.getElementById('test');

var code = {'as':'','db':'','id3':'','term':''};

div.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(code, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

If you just want to output one of the values, use the key to access it

```js
var div = document.getElementById('test');

var code = {'as':'1','db':'2','id3':'3','term':'4'};

div.innerHTML = code.as; // dot notation, or "code['as']" for bracket notation
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I want to print the value of 'as' into a div, like div.innerHTML = code['as'];

Comment: @Jouh - somewhat deliberately, as you weren't very clear, but I added just getting the values of an object as well

Comment: Alright, I'm sorry if my question was inaccurate. I do want to be able to iterate over the array though, but as I understand it iterating is not possible like this and thus creating the described unwanted behaviour.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets on the wisdom of `code.as` vs. `code['as']`

Answer (score 0):

Like this, but since the value is "nothing", the output is "nothing".

```js
var div = document.getElementById('test');

var code = {'as':'','db':'','id3':'','term':''};

// code['as'] = "hello, world";     // un-comment to see something

div.innerHTML = '[' + code['as'] + ']';
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Here is a second idea, based on the revision of your question:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('test');


var keys = ['as', 'db', 'id3', 'term' ];

var code = {};
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) code[keys[i]] = '';

code['as'] = "hello, world";
// code[keys[0]] = "hello, world";      // or this
  
div.innerHTML = '[' + code['as'] + ']' + ' (' + code[keys[0]] + ')';
```

```html
<div id="test">X</div>
```

Comment: Why you need `<pre>`, remove it.

Comment: EDIT: Changed to use '[' and ']' to bracket the value, since it is nothing and therefor hard to see that anything happened.

Comment: Yes, this is an answer I forsaw, though I'm currently looking for a way around all this. I mainly wanted to know where that Undefined came from, and I would like to apologize if that was not clear enough.

Comment: If you find one, let the rest of the world know... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `for..in` loop, `.innerHTML` ; using `break` to stop loop after `as` property printed to `div`

```js
// "predefine" empty strings with `1` , `2, `3`, `4`
var code = {'as':'1','db':'2','id3':'3','term':'4'};

var div = document.querySelector("div");

for (var prop in code) {
  if (prop === "as") {
    div.innerHTML += code[prop];
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Why looping over all properties and check if key is `as`. Just use `code.as`. Simple!

Comment: @Tushar Well, Question , expected results not entirely clear at onset ? Particularly at _"How can I "predefine" the empty string?"_

Comment: @guest271314 It's over-complicated for the question at hand, but the `for (var prop in code)` is probably a useful thing for the questioner to learn.

Comment: @JohnHascall Question at hand still not clear , here. Is _"How can I "predefine" the empty string?"_ no longer part of Question ?

Comment: I am assuming he's asking how to put a value in `code['as']` as in the comment in my answer, but I could easily be wrong given the fractured English...

Comment: Shouldn't you ask / tell the person in question what youre telling each other?

Comment: Define _here_ please, this is your own answer with zero comments from my side before "_Shouldn't you ask / tell the person in question what youre telling each other?_"

Comment: @Jouh "here" is this user . What is requirement ?

Comment: @guest271314 Requirement generally is a word, if I recall my school correctly.

Comment: @Jouh _"Requirement generally is a word, if I recall my school correctly."_ ? What is the requirement of the Question asked ? What is the expected result of the Question asked ? These are what is not certain , here; as the Question appears to have changed from _"How can I "predefine" the empty string?"_ , which also, was not immediately clear , here. Why posted `for..in` loop example to iterate all proerties of object

Comment: There is no requirement for the question, and the expected result is an answer to my question. If unclear, look at my answer, which should explain everything. Please keep in mind that your sidetalk with another person is not constructive if you do not comprehend the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100898/discussion-between-guest271314-and-jouh).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was me trying to call code[i], which is not possible in JavaScript. Undefined popped up because JS tried to evaluate the value to the key, which was not present at first.